# Explain me how libraries are searched in this case

Tags: c++, unix, cmake, shared-libraries, conan

Simplified a little

1. I have a project with 2 targets (subdirectories): first `libMain.so` library, who linked with second `libDependent.so` :

```
add_library( Main SHARED ${cpp} )

target_link_libraries(Main 
    Dependent
)
```

2. I make a conan package, that contains 2 libraries - `libMain.so` and `libDependent.so` inside `/package/CONANPACKAGEID/lib` folder
3. In conan also located FindMainPackage.cmake with example code

```
  find_library (Main_LIBRARIES Main Main_d
    HINTS ${Main_ROOT_DIR} ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    PATH_SUFFIXES lib
    )
```

and find_path

3. In my general project I use find_package(Main) and link my third lib with Main

```
target_link_libraries(General
    ${Main_LIBRARIES}
)
```

or

```
target_link_libraries(General
    Main
)
```

both variants are work

4. And last I linked this lib with my google test binary

```
target_link_libraries( Test
    GTest::GTest
    General
)
```

5. If I set to LD_LIBRARY_PATH a variable `${CONAN_LIB_DIRS_MAIN}` (equal `/package/CONANPACKAGEID/lib`) and **run binary from build dir** from terminal -> it work good, all libs are found
6. But if I try to run w/o (5) I get the output

```
error while loading shared libraries: libDependent.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I check my binary with `ld` command and get the output

```
        libMain.so /.conan/data/package/CONANPACKAGEID/lib/libMain.so (0x00007c815718f000)
        libDependent.so => **not found**
```

If I link my `General` with Dependent

```
target_link_libraries(General
    Main
    Dependent
)
```

all works good and `libDependent.so` located in conan package near with `libMain.so` in `ld` output

My questions:

1. Why my binary know that`libMain.so` inside conan package folder. This conan package are not exists in lib pathes ( check with `ldconfig`)
2. Why my binary cannot find `libDependent.so` automatically
3. How I can fix this or how work with situation right?

Thank you for help, my brain in over after 2days...

Comment: I think in your case`libMain.so` does not contain path to `libDependent.so` in `RUNPATH`. When you explicitly link with `Dependent`, its location is added to `RUNPATH` of `libGeneral.so`, allowing it to be discovered at runtime (IIRC, the search order would be `RUNPATH` of `Main`, then `RUNPATH` of executable).

Comment: Why would you be creating ``FindMainPackage.cmake``, and not using one of the conan generators, like ``CMakeDeps``, so it creates automatically it for the consumers? ``CMakeDeps`` automatically handles transitive dependencies, something that seems you are not doing in your code.

Comment: @Osyotr, thank you, Didn't know about ```RUNPATH```

Comment: drodri,
1) I don't have enough practical experience with Conan
2)I want understand how it works by doing it by hand

Comment: Check runpath for both `Main`, what does it contain when you don't link with `Dependent` explicitly? Also for `General`